# Implementing BDF2 for ODEs in Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to implement the Backward Differentiation Formula of order 2 in Matlab and I've been stuck for more than a day. The goal is to solve the Van der Pol equation. I can't find a functioning example for this algorithm on the internet. My attempt so far:

```
clear; clc; close all;

u0=[1;0]; %initial value
t0=0; tf=3000; %interval
h=0.25; %step size
N = floor((tf-t0)/h)+1; %number of points
mu = 100; %Van der Pol parameter
f = @(t,y) vanderpoldemo(t,y,mu);
t = t0:h:tf;

u = zeros(2,N);
u(:,1)=u0;

%% BDF2
u(:,2)=u(:,1)+h*f(t(1),u(:,1));  %estimate starting value
jacobian = @(x) [0,1; -mu*x(1)*x(2)-1,mu*(1-x(1)^2)];
G = @(x,i) [x(1);x(2)]-4/3*u(:,i-1)+1/3*u(:,i-2)-2/3*h*f(t(i),[x(1);x(2)]);
eps = 1e-07; 
%Newton iteration
for i = 3:N
    e = 1;
    x = u(:,i-1);
    while e>eps
    A = eye(2) - 2*h/3*jacobian(x);
    b = G(x,i);
    temp = A\b;
    x = x-temp;
    e = norm(temp);
    end
    u(:,i) = x;
end
```

No matter how small I make the step size, the script simply refuses to return any acceptable results. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: When I tried to run the script, including making tf shorter, it was taking unreasonably long, so I suspect your while loop is simply not converging. Try examining norm(jacobian(x)), I suspect it is quite large such that your Newton iteration is likely to fail.

Comment: @Ian that was my suspicion as well, but then how can I solve this?

Comment: Well, you have $x_{k+1}=x_k - A(x_k)^{-1} b(x_k)$, that's a fixed point iteration that will only converge if the norm of the  Jacobian of the nonlinear map $x \mapsto x-A(x)^{-1} b(x)$ is less than 1, which means the map $x \mapsto A(x)^{-1} b(x)$ can't deviate from the identity by too much. I suspect for mu as large as you have it, this will only be true for h so small that it is impractical to run all the way to tf=3000. But then, I don't have much intuition for what that vector field $b(x)$ looks like.

Comment: A good place to start so that you have something to analyze is to cap the number of Newton iterations and give a warning when you exit the loop due to non-convergence. Then you'll at least have data to look at, but it will probably be gibberish.

Comment: Perhaps this would be more suited to [Superuser Stackexchange](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127189/implementing-bdf2-for-odes-in-matlab. The immediate problem is that something goes wrong in `G`, at least running it in octave. Monitoring the computed values of `b`, in the second or third loop the values are not small as the theory predicts. Using the formula directly and reducing the step size makes the script run correctly.

Comment: @LutzLehmann you are correct, using the formula directly makes the Newton root iteration behave as desired